# How can I implement Kendo.DropDowmList that show different cultures with the culture flag image?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, localization, globalization, kendo-dropdown

I have a Kendo.DropDownList that is populated with different cultures (English, Spanish, Portuguese, Germany)

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
        .Name("culture")
        .DataValueField("Value")
        .DataTextField("DisplayText")
        .DataSource(dataSource =>
        {
            dataSource.Read(read =>
            {
                read.Action("PopulateCultures", "CultureSelector");

            }).Events(e => e.Error("CheckError"));
        })
        .Events(events =>
        {
            events.Select("onCultureChange").DataBound("onDataBound");
        })
)
```

I'm looking for the way to add a template for this dropdown, so it shows culture's Flag image as well.

How do I do that?

Comment: Take a look at the Kendo MVC demos, this [example](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/dropdownlist/template) should do exactly what you are looking for. Basically you will need to use `.Template` and `.ValueTemplate` to render the flag icon in the dropdownlist

Comment: Thank you. I saw that example before. This example assumes that I have images for the countries's flag already. I'm looking for something that would generate images based on culture. I may have countries speaking Spanish, but they can be Mexico, Brasile, Portuguese all speaking the same language but have different flag. Or Germany and Austria having the same language but different flags

Comment: I don't know of anything that generates culture flags on the fly based on culture. You need to supply your own images. Whats the problem with that? Most of the time it would be preferred to supply your own images so you can control image size, format, quality that suite your needs.